# how to download video content from server into a my downloads folder,not on the physical device memory

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I designed a system that allows high school students to sign up,log in and watch video material as well download/read pdf books for maths and science.The system will be on an offline server at each school.I would like to allow students to download the video content,but not save it on their device memory,rather it must appear under a MY DOWNLOADS folder on the system when the students logs into their account.how do i achieve the downloading task?Im using php and mysql for backend

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38557672/1155833)

---

> Try using the download attribute.

```
<a href="myvideo.mp4" download>Download</a>
```

> More at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

---

Additional info in [`<a>` element specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) of Mozzila