# Is this the right approach to download videos in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to make a project to learn more about React, I'm trying to download a video from a URL, I searched online but I only found this code that works for me.. although it's accessing the dom Directly. I heard it a lot of times, it's the wrong thing to do in React.

```
const downloadFile = (url) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = blobURL;
        a.download = 'video.mp4';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
        a.remove();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert('Failed to download file!');
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false); 
      });
  };
```

if there is a better way please let me know!
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download link for video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557641/download-link-for-video-file)

Comment: Nope, i already tried this code , didn't work , it takes me to the video URL.
for example if the video URL is 'example.com/watch?v=qP0MHfNl891' it just takes me to another tab and show the video. does not download it.

Comment: That's not a video URL though... that's a website with a video in it. Are you trying to create a button to download a YouTube video? This smells of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), please ensure you update your question to include the full context on what you're trying to do.